# return the column name for a column containig a text value

Tags: python, string, pandas, indexing

I have a messy dataset. Each row has 8 words scattered in 196 columns. the task is to find the column containing the word in each row.Example: the word 'Paid' can be in any of the 196 columns, but we know it's there. We need to know which column it's in. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: for the other data , is it blank or some kind of number ？

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think it would be easier for us to help you if you provided a small example table to better illustrate your question. For more information, please read our guide on writing a [mcve].

Comment: Each row has 200 columns. Columns 4:196 have either NaN or one of the 8 words.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome Niayesh! an example table sounds like a great idea! I will post one tomorrow when I get on the computer.

Comment: @LeeJack the otheo columns are just garbage that I don't need and values can be replaced. I just can't drop them because each column has one of the words potentnally in one or more of the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `eq` + `idxmax` is simplest here for a few words and exact matches with the guarantee that it's there. Since it's only 8 words, perhaps just a list comprehension and concatenate the results:

#### Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
l = ['']*192 + ['paid', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.choice(l, replace=False, size=196)
                   for i in range(5)])
```

#### Code:

```
pd.concat([df.eq(word).idxmax(1).rename(word) for word in ['paid', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']], 
          axis=1)

#   paid  foo  bar  baz
#0   112  167  184  142
#1   186   93   17  173
#2    56  142  179   67
#3    15   78   38   79
#4   116   84   18   61
```

---

If you only need to check columns [4:196] use `df.iloc[:, 4:197].eq(word)` instead of checking every column

Comment: Thank you @ALollz that's exactly what I was looking for!